# 10.3 % 2.5 prints 0.3 or 0.3000000000000007

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, floating-point, python-3.5

Can someone please explain in detail why in Python 2.7

```
10.3 % 2.5 => 0.3
```

and in Python 3.0 prints `0.3000000000000007` (probably due to representation issues)

And, moreover, `10.3 % 2.5 - 0.3` prints `7.216449660063518e-16` in both Pythons.

The error I can imagine that is due to float representation, but why the change in print behavior and what can be done to avoid it when converting programs from 2 to 3?

Answer (score 0):

A solution for your problem is to use [round](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) so you will always be guaranteed pre-determined accuracy of your floats. So your equation would become

```
round(10.3 % 2.5, 1)
```

Which will in all versions return `0.3`.